# Protect java string value and case?

Tags: java

I have a java class in my project where I define and declare constants. 
In that class I am declaring a variable like:

```
public static final String ACCESS_CODE = "A2mkbQ1";
```

This is a final String. And I don't want it to be modified anywhere in my project by someone else, even it's CASE. 
But if I apply `.toUpperCase()` or `.toLowerCase()` on the `String` `ACCESS_CODE` it changes the case of the string. 
I know nobody can modify this ACCESS_CODE string. But I want them to stop invoking the above methods on the string when comparing this string with another.

How can I protect both `value and case` of the string?

Comment: You can't. And you shouldn't care. If client code is using the value incorrectly, that's their problem.

Comment: Anyway that wont change contents of `ACCESS_CODE` but you cannot restrict public APIs usage defined by a class. The only thing is usage of something wrapper which create lot of mess in your code.

Comment: String is immutable, If you call .toUpperCase() or .toLowerCase() - you receive new String

Comment: They're not modifying the string.  They're creating a new one.  The only way to prevent people from *copying* the string is to remove it from the code entirely so they can't see it.

Comment: You shoud develop your own implementation, that will have no methods and expose nothing. Such class will completely protect data, but be completely useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know nobody can modify this ACCESS_CODE string

Actually you can do this with reflection, but if you actually do this, WTF.

> But I want them to stop invoking the above methods on the string when comparing this string with another.

This won't prevent them from creating an upper or lower case version of this string.

To do this you would have to hack the String class, which is likely to be a bad idea.

If the access code is changed the security shouldn't allow it and you will pick this up in testing.

I can write the following anywhere.

```
 String ACCESS_CODE = "A2MKBQ1";
```

Or I can use a loop to convert the case instead of `toUppercase()`

Comment: they still can call `String my = ACCESS_CODE.toUpperCase()`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou you can cause String.toUpperCase() to throw an exception if you do this by hacking the class (or instrumentation) but I doubt this is a good idea.

Comment: Hmm, really interesting! Throwing `RuntimeException`, or better `AccessCodeUnauthorizedAccessError` on any attempt to call any string method, even `toString()`. By the way, is it possible to make only on concrete instance? Or entire `String` class will be affected?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou it would be the entire String however you could check the contents before throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You've made it a publicly accessible `String`, so your talk about "protecting" it is completely off. Besides, it will be accessible through reflection anyway, so even if you made it private there's no way to "protect" it.

Why do you even think that you need to prevent code from using it, especially since you've made it publicly accessible? What do you do with it and how would you think that someone can abuse it?

Answer (score 0):

A String is always immutable in Java, even if you don't declare it as final. What methods like `toUpperCase()` do is return a *new* string.

And no, you cannot prevent someone from invoking these methods on a `String` object.

Comment: @Pillar: I am not that sure: "But if I apply .toUpperCase() or .toLowerCase() on the String ACCESS_CODE it changes the case of the string"

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a final variable. By calling toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() you get a new string returned by those methods. Your variable will stay the same

Comment: Right, but the reason is not that the variable is final.